# Fill in Column with values from another column if statement(s)

Tags: excel, vbscript

I currently have a VBScript that takes in an Excel document and re-formats it into another Excel document that's more organized.
This code must also look at the values of the CATALOG column ("B1") and place it in the Drawings column ("M1") ONLY if the beginning of the value starts with "EDASM", "EDBSM" etc., yet the "ED" prefix must be eliminated when it's moved.

For example, Catalog number EDF12-01114 would result in nothing being placed in the drawings column, but with EDSM10265, we would need SM10265 to be placed in the drawings column (drop the "ED").

All I've got so far is this, which isn't even complete:

```
Set objRange = objWorkSheet.Range("M1").EntireColumn
IF
    objWorkSheet.Range("B1").Row = "EDF*" THEN 'Maybe correct-ish? Not sure about syntax
    objRange = Null
Else 
    objRange = ("B1") 'Totally an awful guess, but I have no clue what to put here
End If
```

I've seen similar code that has loops and whatnot, but none of them seem to be doing what I need to be done. Thank you!

**EDIT: Current code based off of BruceWayne's. Still doesn't return anything in Excel datasheet's Drawing column, but it looks like it's closer...**

```
Sub move_Text()
Dim lastRow, nextRow, cel , rng 

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row ' Since your Col. B is the data, let's find that column's last row
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lastRow, 2))

nextRow = 1

For Each cel In rng
If Left(cel.Value, 3) <> "EDF" Then
    Cells(nextRow, 13).Value = Mid(cel.Value, 3, Len(cel.Value) - 2)
    nextRow = nextRow + 1
End If
Next

End Sub
```

**Another edit!**
Catalog column is now "C", not "B". Also, I have two header rows, so the first catalog number is located in "C3".

Thanks again! We're getting closer.

Here's the Google Drive files: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2MeeQ3BKptFYnZfQWpwbTJxMm8&usp=sharing

**IMPORTANT TO REMEMBER**

In the Google Drive files: **TestScript.vbs** is the file where all the code is. When the script is run, select **ExcelImport**. That should return **FinalDocument**

Comment: Are you checking if the first 2 characters = "ED"?  Or are you just looking for "EDASM" and "EDBSM"? Or do you have a list: "EDASM", "EDBSM","EDJASM", "EDKBSM"...ect.

Comment: Everything is going to have the first two characters as "ED", but if it's "EDF" I need a null value transferred into column M. If it's anything other than "EDF": "EDASM", "EDBSM","EDJASM", "EDKBSM"...ect, it needs to drop the prefix "ED" and move the value over

Comment: Since you **know** it will all start with "ED", why not use `If Left(Range("B1"),2)="ED" Then ...`. That way you can avoid any pitfalls with a wildcard (off the top of my head, I can't remember if Excel will read your line as literally looking for `ED*` or if it recognizes the `*` as a wildcard).

Comment: I'm assuming you're addressing the first if statement I've got. So then shouldn't I use `If Left(Range("B1"),3)="EDF" Then ...` to sort out all of the nulls? Also, is the syntax of `objRange = Null` correct?

Comment: @ThomasInzina any advice on the code below by BruceWayne?

Comment: @ThomasInzina can you go back to the chat and clarify on your messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
Sub move_Text()
    Dim lastRow, nextRow, cel, rng

    'get last row with data in Column B
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    'set your range starting from Cell B2
    Set rng = Range("B2:B" & lastRow)

    'loop through all the cells in the range to check for "EDF" and "ED"
    For Each cel In rng
        'below condition is to check if the string starts with "EDF"
        If cel.Value Like "EDF*" Then
            'do nothing
        'below condition is to check if the string starts with "ED"
        ElseIf cel.Value Like "ED*" Then
            'drop first two characters of cell's value and write in Column M
            cel.Offset(0, 11).Value = Right(cel.Value, Len(cel.Value) - 2)
        'else condition will be executed when none of the above two conditions are satisfied
        'else condition is based on the link mentioned in your question that will handle words like "ELECTRICAL BOX"
        Else
            'write cell's value in Column Q
            cel.Offset(0, 11).Value = cel.Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT :** For VBScirpt
**________________________________________________________________________________**

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lastRow, nextRow, cel, rng

    Const xlShiftToRight = -4161
    Const xlUp = -4162
    Const xlValues = -4163
    Const xlWhole = 1
    Const xlPrevious = 2

    With objWorksheet
        'get last row with data in Column B
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        'set your range starting from Cell B2
        Set rng = .Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
    End With

    'loop through all the cells in the range to check for "EDF" and "ED"
    For Each cel In rng
        'below condition is to check if the string starts with "EDF"
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "EDF", 1) = 1 Then
            'do nothing
        'below condition is to check if the string starts with "ED"
        ElseIf InStr(1, cel.Value, "ED", 1) = 1 Then
            'drop first two characters of cell's value and write in Column M
            cel.Offset(0, 10).Value = Right(cel.Value, Len(cel.Value) - 2)
        'else condition will be executed when none of the above two conditions are satisfied
        'else condition is based on the link mentioned in your question that will handle words like "ELECTRICAL BOX"
        Else
            'write cell's value in Column M
            cel.Offset(0, 10).Value = cel.Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This definitely looks like what I want, yet it is still returning nothing.

Comment: None at all. It is running and generates the new excel, the values in the M column are just missing

Comment: @cdomination - Well, I've tested this code and its running fine for me. Is it possible for you to share your file so that I can look into it.

Comment: The only files I have are the ones that are posted already. I literally just copied and pasted your code in to my already existing script. I even tried `Call move_Text`, but it's still not working and seems like it's ignoring it. To be clear, you're 1) running the script, it's 2) prompting you to enter info and select an Excel doc and then 3) returning a newly formatted Excel doc?

Comment: @cdomination - Just want to make sure that your data column is `Column B`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. How/where should I share the file?

Comment: @cdomination - You can upload it on any of the online file sharing site and share the link here.

Comment: The link has been shared through Google Drive

Comment: All I had to do after that was Call Demo! Thank you very much, finally a solution

Answer (score 1):

How's this work for you?

```
Sub move_Text()
Dim lastRow&, nextRow&
Dim cel As Range, rng As Range

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row ' Since your Col. B is the data, let's find that column's last row
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lastRow, 2))

nextRow = 1

For Each cel In rng
    If Left(cel.Value, 2) = "ED" Then
        Cells(nextRow, 13).Value = Mid(cel.Value, 3, Len(cel.Value) - 2)
        nextRow = nextRow + 1
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

It will set the range to be your Column B, from row 1 to the last row. Then, loop through each cell in there, checking the left two letters. If "ED", then move the data, but take off the "ED".

Edit: Just realized you're using VBScript. Remove the `as Range` and `&` from the declarations, so it's just `Dim lastRow, nextRow, cel, rng`.

Comment: It's not letting me run it, I keep on getting an error "Expected end of statement" on the `Sub move_Text()` line. Code 800A0401 Error

Comment: @ChristinaDocenko - Hm, do you have any other macros? Are you placing this in a worksheet module? Did you copy/paste the above?

Comment: I don't have any macros and I'm currently editing the file in Notepad++. I copied and pasted your code. I deleted the &'s after last/next row and that took care of the one. Now it doesn't like the next line `Dim cel As Range, rng As Range` at character 9

Comment: I took out the "As" definitions and now it's running again, yet it still isn't working correctly. Is it because we didn't define what cel was?

Comment: @ChristinaDocenko - Ah, I didn't realize you're using VBScript. You should be able to run this if you remove the `&` and `as Range` from the `Dim` lines.

Comment: @ChristinaDocenko - Even with that, it's still not running? Can you step through it with `F8` and see if it's at least running? Perhaps it's not setting the range?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114767/discussion-between-christina-docenko-and-brucewayne).

Answer (score 1):

If your criteria is met, this will copy values (minus the ED prefix) from Column B to Column M.

```
Sub move_Text()
Dim lastRow , i 

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To lastRow
    If Left(Cells(i, 3), 2) = "ED" And Not (Left(Cells(i, 3), 3) = "EDF") Then
        Cells(i, 13).Value = Right(Cells(i, 3, Len(Cells(i, 3)) - 2)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: In assuming that `lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row` still, the code still isn't working. Also, it's actually column C we are copying from, but a simple change to `Cells(i,3)` should've fixed that. Plus, since it's VBScript, I can't us "as..." identifiers

Answer (score 0):

Why not use some of excel's formulas to speed the whole thing up:

```
Sub My_Amazing_Solution ()

    Range("M3").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(TRIM(LEFT(RC[-10],2))=""ED"",RIGHT(TRIM(RC[-10]),LEN(RC[-10])-2),"""")"
    Range("M3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("M3:M" & Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
    Range("M3:M" & Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    Range("M3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End sub
```

This should do it for you!