# Excel - If cell contains specific text

Tags: excel, function

Looking for a function that will search the row it's in and see if it contains a specific String.
Example excel spreadsheet:

```
Column E        Column G
NOT FOUND       G = Column A
FOUND           <leave blank>
FOUND           <leave blank>
null            G = Column A
```

I've tried:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(SEARCH({"NOT FOUND","null"},E2)),G2=E2,"")
```

Comment: you want the row searched, or a cell within the row?  Is column G supposed to be a string or expected results?

Comment: Did you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838838/fill-in-column-with-values-from-another-column-if-statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=IF(OR(E2="NOT FOUND",E2="null"),A2,"")
```

Comment: Thank you @AbeGold

Answer (score 3):

I will assume you are not trying to find the exact match of the entire contents of the cells in Column E.  If you are then @Abe's formula is the best.

If you are trying to search for those words in a longer string then:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(1*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"NOT FOUND","null"},E2)))),A2,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Abe's answer is simpler for the full string search.  I also like this answer because its keeping with the op's original thought process.  NO BIAS to sumproduct 8)

Comment: @ForwardEd `NO BIAS to sumproduct` riiiiiiiight

Comment: Ed likes to describe his intimate relationship with sumproduct to me. Edit: I caught him flirting with aggregate the other day but he's just imitating our playboy friend Bruce.